# How to set simple arrow shape to edge with cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'd like to set arrow shape like '->' to edges with cytoscape.js.

Is there are any way to set it? or can I set the shape by extension?

Comment: Relevant PR that you made on Github : https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/pull/1020

Comment: Yes, I made a PR to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

add below style to edge style in js code:

```
'curve-style': 'bezier',
'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
```